# Does the Black Box heal multiple times if it hits multiple people?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-soldier

Does the Soldier's Black Box heal multiple times for +15 a piece if it hits multiple people, or is it only +15 if it hits anybody at all?

Can this effect crit? (can any healing crit in TF2 or have I played WoW too long...)

Comment: Both (mutually exclusive) answers are posted, but for some reason the one that offers a testing method isn't voted as highly.  What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, you heal more if you hit multiple people**. I just tested this.
However the GUI displays the +15 over each other.

If you want to try it yourself, I can recommand using [tr_walkway](http://forums.tf2maps.net/showthread.php?t=8909). Just set constant resupply off and bot movement speed to zero.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. The more people caught in the splash damage, the better.

The healing effect can't crit, but will heal the full amount even if you barely deal damage to them.

Comment: "It can't crit" Even now after Valve removed "No critical hits" from a bunch of weapons and replaced it with -25% damage?

Comment: @Powerlord I'm referring to the healing effect. Let me edit that clarification.

Comment: I don't think this is right, are you saying if your rocket hits 3 people, you'd get healed 45? Because I think you only get healed 15 regardless of *how many* people it hits.

Comment: I agree with Dunhamzzz - If the black box hits anyone, regardless of how much damage it does (or how many people it hits) it will heal 15.